# Why Eureka registers itself with the wrong URL?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

Trying to configure my eureka registry, everything seems to be ok, the app starts and displays the info about its instance.
The problem I'm facing is that it keeps registering the wrong url as its node. In particular it keeps adding the `/eureka` suffix to the path.

This is my pom (very standard):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>registry</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>registry</name>
    <description>Project Registry Server</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--BEGIN EE modules disabled/removed after Java 8-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--END EE modules disabled/removed after Java 8-->
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

while this is the main class:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class RegistryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RegistryApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Last, my application properties:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8761
spring:
  application:
    name: project-registry
eureka:
  client:
    fetchRegistry: false
    registerWithEureka: false
```

As showed by the startup log, it registers itself at `http://localhost:8761/eureka/` which is not correct, since the dashboard shows at `http://localhost:8761`.

```
2019-04-06 21:14:28.436  INFO 16563 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-04-06 21:14:28.851  INFO 16563 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2019-04-06 21:14:28.868  INFO 16563 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2019-04-06 21:14:28.868  INFO 16563 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Client configured to neither register nor query for data.
2019-04-06 21:14:28.872  INFO 16563 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1554578068871 with initial instances count: 0
2019-04-06 21:14:28.897  INFO 16563 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initializing ...
2019-04-06 21:14:28.899  INFO 16563 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Adding new peer nodes [http://localhost:8761/eureka/]
2019-04-06 21:14:29.016  INFO 16563 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2019-04-06 21:14:29.016  INFO 16563 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2019-04-06 21:14:29.016  INFO 16563 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2019-04-06 21:14:29.016  INFO 16563 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2019-04-06 21:14:29.126  INFO 16563 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Replica node URL:  http://localhost:8761/eureka/
2019-04-06 21:14:29.135  INFO 16563 --- [           main] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Finished initializing remote region registries. All known remote regions: []
2019-04-06 21:14:29.136  INFO 16563 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initialized
```

Here the info showed by the dashboard:
[image]

What's missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you left the **defaultZone** in the configuration file, it sould be:

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

A part of that, one thing is the url that shows the dashboard, which is without "/eureka":

```
http://localhost:8761
```

and another thing is where services are registered, which is with "/eureka"

```
http://localhost:8761/eureka
```